# Quicktime Player Resizing Window

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, media-player, quicktime

How can I resize the window while a video is opened with Quicktime Player freely?

For instance resizing the width resizes the length along with it, vice versa. I wouldn't mind to have black bars on the top and bottom of the video to have the ability to resize the window freely, how can I achieve this?

In finder preview of a video I'm able to freely move the window, example gif: https://i.imgur.com/yYgXMHj.mp4

In Quicktime Player I'm unable, example gif: https://i.imgur.com/1vFDu2g.mp4

Comment: This would be the expected behavior on macos when holding down the shift key while resizing. Maybe try it with shift?

Comment: It does the same thing with or without holding the shift key.

Comment: I have also tried VLC media player, having same issue as Quicktime Player and I can't figure out how to solve it on either of them.